# How to write new line in Java FileOutputStream

Tags: java, newline, fileoutputstream

I want to write a new line using a `FileOutputStream`; I have tried the following approaches, but none of them are working:

```
encfileout.write('\n');
encfileout.write("\n".getbytes());
encfileout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
```

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: its not writing new line

Comment: @PavanPatidar: It is writing a newline. For sure.

Comment: Try executing encfileout.write("Fant".getbytes()); encfileout.write("\n".getbytes()); encfileout.write("astic".getbytes()); If you see the whole word on a single line your problem is confirmed. Especially, the encfileout.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getbytes()); should work.

Comment: @Teddy it is working on localhost but when i am deploying in on my server it does't works.

Comment: It could be a viewer problem... Try opening the file in EditPlus or Notepad++. Windows Notepad may not recognise line feed of another operating system. In which program are you viewing the file now?

Comment: @Teddy:Thanks, you are right its viewing problem, notepad++ is showing correctly my data. Thanks again for bring my attention.

Comment: @PavanPatidar I added the last comment as an answer... you can accept if it solved your problem. If you accept it, this question will be marked as answered.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It could be a viewer problem... Try opening the file in EditPlus or Notepad++. Windows Notepad may not recognize the line feed of another operating system. In which program are you viewing the file now?

Answer (score 20):

This should work. Probably you forgot to call `encfileout.flush()`.

However this is not the preferred way to write texts. You should wrap your output stream with `PrintWriter` and enjoy its `println()` methods:

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(encfileout, charset));
```

Alternatively you can use `FileWriter` instead of `FileOutputStream` from the beginning:

```
FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("myfile");
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(fw);
```

Now just call

```
writer.println();
```

And do not forget to call `flush()` and `close()` when you finish your job.

Comment: I hope you don't mind that i added the missing charset parameter.

Comment: @Pavan Could you explain why it's not what you're looking for so the answer can be amended/another answer provided?

Comment: FileWriter and PrintWriter are feature rich. The println() of Printwriter works great!!!

Answer (score 4):

To add a line break use

```
fileOutputStream.write(10);
```

here decimal value `10` represents newline in ASCII

Answer (score 4):

```
String lineSeparator = System.getProperty("line.separator");
<br>
fos.write(lineSeparator.getBytes());
```

Comment: Please consider adding some form of explanation with your answer. Code only answers are typically discouraged.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
Fos.write(System.lineSeparator().getBytes()).
it worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).